# How to keep the locale during Ajax requests in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Ajax function in Rails where the chosen value of a select box changes the available options inside another:

```
# application.js
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_billing_address_types',
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});

# get_billing_address_types.js.erb
$('#project_billing_address_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@types)) %>");
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work since I localised my app for two different languages.

When I now change the value of the first select box, I get an error inside the other:

```
<option value="h">translation missing: en.views.home</option>
```

Is there any way to pass the locale to javascript at all?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you preserving the URL in non XHR requests? You can simply pass it as a query string parameter to the url. Then use a before_filter to set the I18n locale to that passed parameter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base

  before_filter :select_locale

  def select_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || "en"
  end
```

The application controller is generally where i do that sort of thing, but you can put it in a specific controller to restrict usage if you prefer.